# What's the correct way to structure a project in ASP.NET MVC with an Angular SPA inside it?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, projects-and-solutions

I have an ASP.NET MVC project that will have an Angular SPA inside it. At first, I decided to create a new Area for the SPA but then I realized that I'm not going to use any Models or Controllers inside the area but just JavaScript files. So, now my idea is to place all the scripts for the SPA in the main ~\Scripts\ folder of the ASP.NET MVC project but inside another folder ~\Scripts\MySPAName\ and load the SPA just trough a ASP.NET MVC View.

What's the best way to structure a project in this scenario?

Comment: how do you get data for your SPA? Is that a separate API? Do you use `$http` to get data?

Comment: Yes, I get it from a separate API.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you want to create such kind of project I suggest you use MVC + WebAPI + Angularjs. You really need only 2 MVC controllers: `Account` for all login/logout logic and `Home` with only one simple method `Index` This Index method returns view which contains only one line of code - `div` or `section` or whatever you want `ng-view` attribute. This will be your main application page. Why its better to use WebAPI? Because these controllers works faster than MVC ones and WebAPI provide you with great REST possibility. What bout project structure. I can suggest you my personal structure of MVC + Angularjs project:

[image]

So you have `API` folder for WebAPI controllers, standard `Controllers` folder for MVC controllers. In `Scripts` folder you have separate folders for your angular controllers services ang general libraries and one .js file - its your angular module and application file. Moreover, its better and cleaner if you have additional subfolders in `Scripts/Controllers` folder so you can split all you *.js file by category (e.g Home, Mangers, Prices etc). Also you can see that I have folder `Templates` in root of my project. Here you can place all your `html` files which you will use as `angular` views/templates. And I also suggest you to create additional subfolders here as in `Scripts/Controllers` subfolder for better and cleaner structure

Hope that will help you

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC is better suited to traditional web sites. For a single page app, use ASP.NET Web API instead. Here's a tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-(spa)-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs

Comment: My ASP.NET MVC consists of more than one module and one of the modules is this SPA.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In this, There are two web projects, one is or web api and another one is for client web page (SPA).

You just need a empty web project to start an angular project.

Index.html - It is the main html page for your application. All other pages (partial pages) for your project can be placed Inside the directory `Pages`.

Scripts - All your js files can be placed inside this directory. You can differentiate all your js files into it's sub-directories.

Comment: I would also use ngbp(https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp or https://github.com/thardy/generator-ngbp) for better SPA structure. Grunt can be also integrated into VS.